# Play framework: how to pass parameters extracted in the onRequest function

Tags: java, playframework

I overwrote the `public Action onRequest(final Http.Request request, Method method)` method to check that the mandatory http headers are passed in and valid, i.e.: I extract the apiKey (and other things) and make sure that these are valid (that there's data associated with the apiKey).  Then I call `return super.onRequest(request, method);` and I end up in my controller where I once again have to extract the apiKey and get the associated data from the DB.
Is there a way to pass in the data to my controller's method (for instance: `public static Result addUser()` ).

Thank you.

Comment: What play version do you use? GlobalSettings is deprecated in 2.5

Answer (score 0):

*I know this question is for Java, but I work with Play in Scala, and this question is more related to Play then it is to Java*

In **Scala** I am able to extend `WrappedRequest` to make my own custom request type, that has instance variables I want to access in my controller:

```
// Scala code
case class MyRequest[A](request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest(request) {

  // This is a public instance variable
  val apiKey = request.headers.get("Authorization)   
}
```

Then later on in my controller I can access the action object which now has the type of `MyRequest`:

```
// Scala code
def foobar(action: MyRequest[AnyContent]) = Action {

  // Do something with the api key
  val apiKey = action.apiKey

  // Send back a response
  Ok("foobar")
}
```

In **Java** it looks like you can do something similar using a [Wrapped Context](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/java/play/mvc/Http.WrappedContext.html)